# Logback prints its own logs to console after device change

Tags: java, logging, console, jvm, logback

Logback has started acting weirdly. I reset my computer recently and everything works great but since I "changed" the device, Logback is outputting the following stuff into the console. I do not know if this is related to the device change but I cannot come up with anything else.

```
17:58:22,416 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
17:58:22,417 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
17:58:22,417 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/ich/IdeaProjects/AutoVoice/build/resources/main/logback.xml]
17:58:22,506 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
17:58:22,510 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
17:58:22,516 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:58:22,538 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
17:58:22,538 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
17:58:22,539 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
17:58:22,540 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@458c1321 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

This is sent on every application start. I have a valid logback.xml that is unaltered from the time when it worked. I do not understand why Logback is printing its own logs to my console. This is my logback.xml

```
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I would be thankful for anyone who can explain this to me/tell me how to stop this from happening - it's annoying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I rebuilt the logback.xml file recently (unrelated to device change) using a preset I always use. Somebody seems to have modified it to have `debug="true"` in the first line. Simply removing that (or setting it to `false`) resolved the issue for me.

This is my loback.xml now:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```